# How to convert longitude and latitude to street address

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Given the latitude and longitude, how do we convert it to street address using Javascript or Python?

Comment: Not a broad question at all.

Comment: +1 for legitimate question, I also have the same question

Comment: (Btw, this is called "reverse geocoding.")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get city name from a latitude and longitude point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548504/how-can-i-get-city-name-from-a-latitude-and-longitude-point)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

99% of the time, most people link you to Google Maps's API. Not a bad answer. HOWEVER -- Beware of the prohibited uses, usage limits and [Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12)! While a distributed app many not run afoul of the usage limit, it is quite limiting for a web app. The TOS does not allow you to repurpose Google's data into an app with your skin on it. You would hate to have your business plan derailed by a cease and desist letter from Google, no?

All is not lost. There are several open sources of data, including US Government sources. Here are a few of the best:

The US Census [Tiger Database](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/), in particular, supports reverse geocoding and is free and open for US addresses. Most other databases derive from it in the US.

[Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) and [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) are user supported in the Wikipedia model.

Answer (score 6):

You could try https://mapzen.com/pelias it's open source and actively being developed.

For example: http://pelias.mapzen.com/reverse?lat=40.773656&lon=-73.9596353

returns (after formatting):

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "id":"address-node-2723963885",
            "type":"osmnode",
            "layer":"osmnode",
            "name":"151 East 77th Street",
            "alpha3":"USA",
            "admin0":"United States",
            "admin1":"New York",
            "admin1_abbr":"NY",
            "admin2":"New York",
            "local_admin":"Manhattan",
            "locality":"New York",
            "neighborhood":"Upper East Side",
            "text":"151 East 77th Street, Manhattan, NY"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[-73.9596265, 40.7736566]
         }
      }
   ],
   "bbox":[-73.9596265, 40.7736566, -73.9596265, 40.7736566],
   "date":1420779851926
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the Google Maps API. It has an API function that does exactly this:
http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: That link is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Google Geo API. A sample code for API V3 is available on [my blog](http://javascriptdeveloper.ca/convert-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-to-address-using-google-geocoding-api-v3-javascript-jquery/)

```
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Convert Latitude and Longitude (Coordinates) to an Address Using Google Geocoding API V3 (Javascript)</TITLE>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    var address = new Array();

    /*
    * Get the json file from Google Geo
    */
    function Convert_LatLng_To_Address(lat, lng, callback) {
            var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng + "&sensor=false";
            jQuery.getJSON(url, function (json) {
                Create_Address(json, callback);
            });     
    }

    /*
    * Create an address out of the json 
    */
    function Create_Address(json, callback) {
        if (!check_status(json)) // If the json file's status is not ok, then return
            return 0;
        address['country'] = google_getCountry(json);
        address['province'] = google_getProvince(json);
        address['city'] = google_getCity(json);
        address['street'] = google_getStreet(json);
        address['postal_code'] = google_getPostalCode(json);
        address['country_code'] = google_getCountryCode(json);
        address['formatted_address'] = google_getAddress(json);
        callback();
    }

    /* 
    * Check if the json data from Google Geo is valid 
    */
    function check_status(json) {
        if (json["status"] == "OK") return true;
        return false;
    }   

    /*
    * Given Google Geocode json, return the value in the specified element of the array
    */

    function google_getCountry(json) {
        return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("country", json["results"][0]["address_components"], false);
    }
    function google_getProvince(json) {
        return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("administrative_area_level_1", json["results"][0]["address_components"], true);
    }
    function google_getCity(json) {
        return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("locality", json["results"][0]["address_components"], false);
    }
    function google_getStreet(json) {
        return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("street_number", json["results"][0]["address_components"], false) + ' ' + Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("route", json["results"][0]["address_components"], false);
    }
    function google_getPostalCode(json) {
        return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("postal_code", json["results"][0]["address_components"], false);
    }
    function google_getCountryCode(json) {
        return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("country", json["results"][0]["address_components"], true);
    }
    function google_getAddress(json) {
        return json["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
    }   

    /*
    * Searching in Google Geo json, return the long name given the type. 
    * (if short_name is true, return short name)
    */

    function Find_Long_Name_Given_Type(t, a, short_name) {
        var key;
        for (key in a ) {
            if ((a[key]["types"]).indexOf(t) != -1) {
                if (short_name) 
                    return a[key]["short_name"];
                return a[key]["long_name"];
            }
        }
    }   

  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var geocoder  = new google.maps.Geocoder();             // create a geocoder object
var location  = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);    // turn coordinates into an object          
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': location}, function (results, status) {
if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {           // if geocode success
var add=results[0].formatted_address;         // if address found, pass to processing function
document.write(add);
```

source from https://gist.github.com/marchawkins/9406213/download# it works me