# Show Pins on Map for Current Region

Tags: ios, annotations, maps, xcode4.5

I am working with Maps and i have 2 thousand latitudes and longitudes of germany specific locations in CSV file. It take 3-4 mins to drop all the pins on map when clicked.

I want to that map should open quickly on gps values and show pins for that specific region. if user moves on map then it drops pins but not wait in this all process like we have now about 3-4 mins.

Comment: If i'm not confused, you can find decision http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial/.
I think MKMapItem Class can help you

Comment: @Neznajka actually i know how to drop a pin. but i was user able to see his location (i have done with it). now i want him to show his location (Region) pins only to drop on map.

Comment: @AmiriDev batter for you to use the google api for this.

Comment: The following link will help you. 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548504/how-can-i-get-city-name-from-a-latitude-and-longitude-point

Comment: @JayD I have CSV File for specific locations, I have to use this file to drop pins. I have also tried "KMLViewer", I want to drop pins for current location first or only for Current Region which is shown in map right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Selector and perform it on background and use it on -viewDidLoad method. The use will see the map without any wait

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(readFileAndDropPin) withObject:self];
```