# How can I get a list of closest cities to a given city?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-api, geolocation

I need to get a list of closest cities (in JSON for example) to a given city in a certain radius.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548504/how-can-i-get-city-name-from-a-latitude-and-longitude-point

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @CarlosLaspina thanks, I will try this