# How to find city name with latitude and longitude in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude, city

I already searched in a lot of websites for a solution but no one of them worked.

Since hours I am trying to get the **name of the city** by using the **latitude and longitude** values which I will get from a input box to my `x`, `y` variables but no example worked.

I also read in the Google maps API but it was not useful.

I already have an API key.

Do you maybe have any solution?

This example I got from the website and tried but without success:

```
function myFunction() { var x='xxxxx'; var y='xxxxx'; //my coordinates 
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(x), lng: parseFloat(y)};

    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        // ...
        } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
        }
        } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeD.html

Comment: Wow thats it thank you :) LOVE THIS SITE !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get city name from a latitude and longitude point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548504/how-can-i-get-city-name-from-a-latitude-and-longitude-point)

Answer (score 3):

Look out for [Geo location API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding)

Sample Request

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false